# Persistent request metadata in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there any way for me to have persistent request metadata in a spider? `request.meta` only persists until the next callback, where I have to do something like this:

```
def method1(self, response):
    request = Request(url, callback=self.method2)
    request.meta['persist'] = ...

    yield request

def method2(self, response):
    ...

    request = Request(url, callback=self.method3)
    request.meta['persist'] = response.meta['persist']

    yield request
```

I also made a decorator that does this, but I'm really hoping that there's a cleaner solution:

```
def persist_meta(callback):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for result in callback(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if isinstance(result, Request):
                response = args[0]

                persist = response.meta.get('persist', {})
                persist.update(result.meta.get('persist', {})

                result.meta['persist'] = persist

            yield result

    return inner
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new [middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#writing-your-own-spider-middleware) and put your code to persist the meta in `process_spider_input`.